# DisplayMemberPath working on Combobox but not on ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf

So this is super frustrating. To explain it in details, I have a method to read data from database:

```
public static List<T> LoadTable<T>(string dBTable)
{
    using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
    {
            var output = cnn.Query<T>("select * from " + dBTable, new DynamicParameters());
            return output.ToList();
    }
}
```

I call it like this:

```
    List<Rank> ranks = LoadTable<Rank>("tblRanks");
    cmb.ItemsSource = mnuDg.ItemsSource = ranks;
    cmb.DisplayMemberPath = mnuDg.DisplayMemberPath = "Title";
```

the Combobox easily shows the correct Title but the ContextMenu shows this:

[image]

I'm so confused.
btw I'm using HandyControl but set the Style to {x:Null} to no results.

Comment: Your issue is not reproducible based on the information you have provided here.

Comment: @mm8 yeah it feels like nonsense. idk if it's a bug in HandyControl package or what. Totally confused.